# How to turn off Firefox session store files' compression

Tags: firefox, session-restore

Not sure which Firefox version turned on compressed session store, but seemingly have a situation where not only did the current file not get written in a format `LZ4` tools can decompress, but also the backup files that I know are supposed to exist, be existing (which should be in a better state).

A plaintext file when these files get corrupted (rare in my experience, mind you) is REALLY helpful in these situations, and am fine with the performance degradation that I trust led to this design decision.

Have searched a number of variables in `about:config` without luck. Don't tell me I have to fork each new version to edit the code and remove this feature that should be an option!

Comment: Which session store? Where is it found?

Comment: @harrymc - What other session store is there? https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/session_restore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. The code path does not provide any way to control the compression flag when the sessionstore state is saved.